# jqGrid batch save - how to get all row data in edit mode

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid with 100+ rows that are displayed in Edit mode by default. I am trying to figure out a way to send all row data in one call to the server.

The problem - How to get the row data in edit mode (getRowData method returns the html)?

Once I get all the row data, I can hopefully parse them in a JSON format and send it to the server via jQuery.ajax() call.

Any help in this regard is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I saw Oleg's response to a similar question - ['code']$("#" + rowid + ">td:nth-child(" + (i + 1) + ")>input").val()['code']. This works. However, I have a column that is not editable for some rows, and also some columns are <select> instead of <input> and so the above strategy may involve too much of hard coding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can imagine me many ways to implement you requirements. I would describe you the simplest one. It consist from

- saving of all editing rows. If you use inline editing mode then you need call [saveRow](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing#saverow) for all editing rows. Because `saveRow` tests internally whether the row in editing and because the most rows (probably even all) are already in editing mode, you can just use `getDataIDs` to get array of ids of all rows and then call `saveRow` in the loop for every from returned id.
- usage of `getRowData` without parameters or usage of `getGridParam` to get `"data"` option.
- send the data to the server using [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).
- the last step is optional. You can start editing mode for all the rows.

I think that the above approach is not only mostly easy implemented. It's mostly save, because it works for every editing control (inclusive custom one).

Comment: I had started my implementation in this way but got stuck. Here is my concern with the above approach. When I loop through the array of ids and call saveRow, if there is a validation error on one of the rows e.g. required field, that row will remain in edit mode. And then when I use getRowData, I will get html content for that row. Is there a way, I can add row data to a JSON object when saveRow succeeds for each row? I tried "aftersavefunc" handler of saveRow but it gets called with rowId and true/false.

Comment: On second thought - I guess in "aftersavefunc" I can see if the row is saved successfully or not. If saved successfully, I can then use getRowData using the rowId and then add to a JSON object. I will give this a try but if you have a better implementation, let me know.

Comment: @RRK: You can easy detect validation error (the case that not all rows will be saved and still are in editing mode) by getting `"savedRow"` option (`$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow")`). The returned value is empty array if no rows are editing now.

Comment: Thanks Oleg!! For anyone else facing a similar issue, I followed Oleg's steps but also used "aftersavefunc" handler of saveRow to collect all the successfully saved rows into an array. After all rows are processed, I check to see if there are validation errors using `$("#grid").jqGrid("getGridParam", "savedRow")`, if no validation error, then I make an AJAX call to server sending the array.